# Text Watcher not showing the toast in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-toast

i'm calling the asynctask for the editText in android using **editname.addTextChangedListener(watcher);**  after i typed the character in edit text it not working in android.

```
 private final TextWatcher watcher=new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
            if(s.length()<=4){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type above 4 characters",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                String url="http://10.0.2.2/chat/q.php?username="+s.toString();
                 if(task != null && (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)){
                task.execute(new String[]  {url});
                 }

            }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {


            }

        };
```

my problem is toast not working for my code . plz help

Comment: Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "type above 4 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); try like this.

Comment: try to add your code in onTextChanged

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "type above 4 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Replace `YourActivity` with the name of your `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your activity context besides `getApplicationContext()` in your `Toast`.

> ```
>  Toast.makeText(Mainactivity.this, "type above 4 characters",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> ```